# É possivel realizar uma conexão com PostgreSQL via ODBC no Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi-7, odbc

Estou tendo dificuldades para realizar a conexão com o banco de dados **PostgreSQL** no **Delphi 7**, consegui com o Zeos Lib, porém preciso que seja via **dbExpress** a conexão, então vi que nas versões mais atuais do Delphi é possível realizar a conexão via **ODBC**, porém o **Delphi 7** não disponibiliza essa opção, será que tem algum componente que preciso adicionar para poder realizar tal conexão via **ODBC** no **Delphi 7**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R. Santos para utilizar conexão ODBC é necessário que seja utilizado os componentes ADO, com ele é possível realizar a conexão por meio da lib odbc do PostgreSQL.

Para começar baixe a lib odbc do postgresql https://odbc.postgresql.org/

Em seguida adicione um componente ADOConnection no seu projeto e configure a propriedade ConnectionString selecionando o provider PostgreSQL OLE Provider e preenchendo as demais opções disponíveis para conexão com o banco de dados.

Feito isso ative o ADOConnection e coloque um ADODataSet, especifique o comando SQL e pode utilizar sozinho ou em conjunto ao dataset provider + clientdataset.